# Current Configuration Scope magento

Tags: magento

There is Current Configuration Scope in the magento admin , what is the significane of that and from where we can ad and delete the seemingly useless dropdown in the "Current Configuration Scope:"

Answer (score 5):

Magento has the very powerful ability to host multiple Stores and Websites on a single installation.  The Configuration scope refers to which Website or Store that you are currently managing the settings for.  So that drop-down is actually very important.

You manage the entries in the drop-down under System>Manage Stores, but you can read more on multi-store setups [on the Magento wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/overview-how-multiple-websites-stores-work/) and these [two](http://www.crucialwebhost.com/blog/how-to-setup-multiple-magento-stores/) [blogs](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-set-multiple-websites-with-multiple-store-views-in-magento/).